# Android: Two buttons but the action from pressing one is only taking place after the other is pressed too

Tags: android, button, onclick, switch-statement

I have two buttons in my application, one is to to start Google Voice and the other is to exit the application. However, when I press the voice button, it doesn't do anything until after I press the exit button too. So, the app exits, but then Google Voice starts.

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.btnDisable:{
            //Set the ringer to normal
            audio.setRingerMode(2);
            //Close the text-to-speech engine 
            tts.shutdown();
            //Welcome.bt.disable();
            activity.finish();
            onDestroy();
            break;
        }

        case R.id.btnVoice: {
            System.out.println ("pressed");
            Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "en_US");

            try {
                startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_SPEECH);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
                Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Opps! Your device doesn't support Speech to Text",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                t.show();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you have proper Log output "Pressed" but your intent doesn't start until you press disable button?

Comment: You really shouldn't be having one onClick method for two different buttons.  Consider using the onClick attribute in XML on your buttons, this should make your code a lot more readable, and I've never encountered an issue with it.

Comment: @MarkoLazić No, "Pressed" also doesn't get printed out till after the disable button is pressed.

Comment: @BrandonRomano How do I do that? Sorry, I don't really have much experience with android (i.e. this is my first app :D). So if you could please elaborate.

Comment: Lose {} in switch after case you don't need them

Comment: @MarkoLazić You're right, but that doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: @user2303527, I responded with an answer.  You should use either of those methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this sample, this works properly, adjust names according to your xmls and files, you'll manage with that part

```
public class FindEventsActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

//lots of other code up here
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);             
    setContentView(R.layout.adds);

    findViewById(R.id.bAdd).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.bSub).setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v) {

    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.bAdd:
            //Set the ringer to normal
            System.out.println("Button 1");
            break;

        case R.id.bSub:
            System.out.println ("Button 2");                
            break;
    }
}
}
```

If you still don't see your problem then share some more code.

Hope this helps and enjoy your work

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks a lot! 
For the record, the problem was that I didn't use setOnClickListener (this)

Answer (score 1):

You should either use the `android:onClick` XML attribute, or apply an onClickListener to your button.  These are both standard ways to go about dealing with onClicks.

======== onClick in XML ========

In XML:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="someMethodName"
    />
```

In your Activity:

```
public void someMethodName(View v){
    //Do something
}
```

======== onClickListener ========

in XML:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/someID"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

In your Activity:

```
Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.someID);
myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Do something

        }
    });
```

I've really never seen any variance to these two methods, and I would suggest using either (or both) of these.  Both are accepted ways of handling onClicks.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the break under the closing "}" of the disable button code

Comment: That just stopped the action of Voice button completely i.e. it didn't even start after pressing the Disable button

Comment: share your part where you set onClickListener for both buttons